# Deploy in GitHub by modifying a protected tag

Tags: github, deployment, github-actions

I'm working on transitioning a repository from GitFlow to trunk-based approach. We figured such approach for prod deploys: to deploy a given commit, we need to tag the commit with a tag called `release`. We'd like to protect this tag so that the deployment happens only after approval. Subsequent deployments are done by resetting this tag.

So far I managed to configure an environment where a deployment requires approval of a certain group of people, and create a workflow that performs the deployment (for now, just does nothing) - the approval to run the workflow is indeed enforced. The missing piece is how to protect the `release` tag, but still let the workflow update it.

I'm looking at rulesets for tags. I created one for the `release` tag, adding to the bypass list the same team that is allowed to approve the deployment. However when trying to do `git push -f origin release` in the workflow, I'm getting this error:

```
remote: error: GH013: Repository rule violations found for refs/tags/release.        
remote: Review all repository rules at http://github.com/.../.../rules?ref=refs%2Ftags%2Frelease        
remote: 
remote: - Cannot update this protected ref.        
remote: 
To https://github.com/.../...
 ! [remote rejected] release -> release (push declined due to repository rule violations)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/.../...'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I'm testing it on a setup where both the person creating and approving the workflow is me, and I'm on the team allowed to approve the workflow and modify the tag. It seems that when running the workflow, the `git push ...` is not done on my behalf - looks like an authentication issue.

I thought about creating a machine user (see the tip [here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/learning-about-github/types-of-github-accounts#personal-accounts)), adding it to the bypass list for the tag's ruleset, and using its personal access token to authenticate. However it's not clear to me how to protect the personal access token - anyone in my org could create a workflow that uses the secret and ultimately deploy outside of the only approved workflow.

I'd be grateful for any hints on how to implement this workflow, or alternatively how to modify it so that it's possible to implement it securely in the GitHub world.

Comment: A note to myself: try environment-specific secrets. In theory they should be available only if the workflow running in a given env is approved.